# Insert JSON lines data into mysql using keys as field names

Tags: python, mysql, json, rabbitmq

I need to run a small script that consumes JSON data coming in, processes it into an SQL INSERT to append to an existing table.

This is what I have upto now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
import json
import string
import datetime

cursor = sqldb.cursor()
json_data = open('/home/user/pythonstuff/test.json')
data = json.load(json_data)
table_name = data['name']
datetime_string = data['timestamp']
print(data)
print(table_name)
print(datetime_string)

fields=[]

for i in data:
    fields.append(i[:])

print (fields)

query = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES ('%s',%s,%s,%s...)" % (table_name + 'b', 
for i in fields?)

cursor.execute(query)
self.sqldb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Sample test.json file:

```
{"name": "prototype_1", "timestamp": "2017-11-15 18:28:49.741879", "data1": 48059, "data2": 0, "data3": 0, "switch": true}
```

I'd like to map this data into a mysql table with the same fields (name, timestamp etc)

Comment: What is the issue or error you're running into?

Comment: What is `for i in fields?` supposed to mean?

Comment: thats where im stuck, i cant find a way to add all the fields without explicitly listing them out, there are maybe like 30 fields in total